# Unable to run a simple servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am making my first servlet following this link http://www.roseindia.net/servlets/

This is my servlet in Eclipse ServletDemo->Java Resources->src->(default package)->HelloServlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{ 

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException,IOException{
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
  pw.println("<html>");
  pw.println("<head><title>Hello World</title></title>");
  pw.println("<body>");
  pw.println("<h1>Hello World</h1>");
  pw.println("</body></html>");
  }
}
```

This is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
 PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd"> 

<web-app>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>HelloServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I am using Tomcat server, I had also set Environment variable for servlet-api.jar.
But while running the same I am getting following error:

> HTTP Status 404-Servlet Hello is not available.

Comment: i tried that also created a package and created srvlet inside it, but still its hsowing the same error  had done modification in web.xml also...dono...how to solve this..i am stucked..

Answer (score 2):

Servlets may no longer live in the default package; create a package and move the servlet in to it (depends on what version on Tomcat you're using).

It also matters how you're deploying/running the servlet, as compared to how you're attempting to access it from the browser--you need to specify a context, if you're deploying it to something other than the root context.

(I also tend to point people away from tutorials from that site as they're often... misleading. And while I know this is just a tutorial, bear in mind that generating HTML from inside a servlet like this is essentially never what you want to do :)

Comment: I created java file outside eclipse also and compiled it in console,it got compiled.Then i placed the class file inside tomcat's webapp->myhello->WEB-INF->classes->class file and web.xml inside webapp->myhello->WEB-INF->web.xml..but still its showing same error when iam running it on browser...unable to get it..plzz help..