# Can't access a java servlet

Tags: java

I  have created a java servlet & compiled it. Then I copied .class file in to the classes folder in WEB-INF folder & I updated the web.xml also but when I'm trying to access that using Firefox this error occurs "The requested resource () is not available.". Server is Tomcat7. I'm very new to programing & I don't know how to solve it. I hope your help.
Thanx!

XML

```
<servlet>

<servlet-name>HelloServlets</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>HelloServlets</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>HelloServlets</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet/HelloServlets</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: post the web.xml configuration please

Comment: It's impossible to answer with so few details. Show us the structure of the webapp folder. Tell us where you put this folder, in which servlet container, show us the content of the web.xml and the source code of your servlet, and tell us which URL you're using to invoke the servlet.

Comment: Also, I suggest you should check the "Server" logs and see if there is any error/exception there.

Comment: Also post your url you are trying in your browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to run a simple servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643626/unable-to-run-a-simple-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

First check that you properly deploy your application in **server**.
Search how to deploy application in tomcat. See this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html). Place your project in "webapps" folder and restart server. If using eclipse then you will see server. Open t and select your project to deploy.

Then check that your url is properly mapped to your servlet class.

Try to debug things.

Comment: How can I deploy it in Tomcat server

Comment: Place your project in "webapps" folder and restart server. If using eclipse then you will see server. Open t and select your project to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the correct settings in web.xml you also need to tell you servlet container where is the root of your web-application. this can be done in severals ways. The easiest is by creating a context file, let's say in your case servlets.xml witch may look like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="C:\Java\Projects\Web\MyFirstServlets"
     debug="3" reloadable="true">
</Context>
```

The direcotry `C:\Java\Projects\Web\MyFirstServlets` is the parent of your WEB-INF.

Let's say you are using apache tomcat. Place the file servlets.xml in the subfolder `conf\Catalina\localhost` of your servletcontainer.

set the following servlet-mapping

```
<url-pattern>/HelloServlets</url-pattern>
```

After starting tomcat you should be able to access your servlet like this

```
http://localhost:<port>/servlets/HelloServlets
```